# Error optimized out

Tags: c

```
void disp(char c[][3], char s[9], char so[5])
{

    int m, n, k, a, b;

    a = 0;
    b = 0;

    for (m = 1; m <= 9; m++) {

        for (n = 0; n < 3; n++) {

            for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {

                if (m == c[n][k] || c[n][k] == 'O') {

                    s[b] = m;
                    b++;

                    if (c[n][k] == 'O') {

                        so[a] = m;
                        a++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

En este código al depurar me sale que las variables m y n no tienen valor, me sale optimized out...alguien sabe como solucionar, no puedo optimizar ni eliminarlas ya que todas las variables son contadores de ciclos diferentes. gracias

Comment: Deshabilita las optimizaciones del compilador. Si está usando `gcc`, usa `gcc -O0` para compilar.

Comment: No me sale ninguna alarma al compilar tu código ¿Qué compilador estás usando?, por otro lado ¿Has probado declarr las variables en el bucle en lugar de fuera?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Eso es lo que le sale al depurar si no se puede inspeccionar alguna variable porque las opciones del compilador omitieron su existencia real.

Comment: @Trauma ah... vale. De todas maneras, sigo teniendo la corazonada de que desaparece el problema si las variables las declara en el bucle en lugar de fuera (se va a un rincón a despotricar sobre las variables cuyo nombre es una sola letra y están declaradas fuera de sitio).

Comment: Gracias @Trauma, no me habia pasado hasta ahora...es por un máximo de variables en el programa o por algun algoritmo de optimizacion del compilador? Ah y es C, no C++, por lo de declarar variables en el bucle

Comment: Es por el compilador, que hace bien su trabajo :-) Si la variable tiene un uso localizado, y se usa muchas veces , el compilador usa un registro interno de la CPU en lugar de una posición de memoria. Piensa siempre que es *desde el punto de vista del compilador*. Igual optimiza cosas que tu no esperas, o al revés, no puede optimizar aquello que tú ves fácil. Son muchas cosas las que influyen :-)

Comment: @Trauma Puede ser que la linea de comandos que necesta es: `gcc -O0 -g3` o `-g1`, con alguna de esas `-g`'s debe de aparecerle información respecto a las variables en el depurador.

Comment: @NaCI Buen *trick*, no conocía esas -g ... me las anoto :-)